# d3.js function to filter the interactive chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3.js and I am trying to customize an interactive chart. I want to add "Location" dropdown filters to chart and it should show only the selected Location's data. But not able to achieve it.

[reference chart example](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/96447623ef4d342ee09b)

This is where i got stuck:

```
                dropDown.on("change", function () {
                var selected = this.value;
                displayOthers = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";
                display = this.checked ? "none" : "inline";

                hGsvg.selectAll(".bar").data(data[this.value])
                    .filter(function() {return (selected != sF) ;})
                    .attr("display", displayOthers);


                hGsvg.selectAll(".bar").data(data[this.value])
                    .filter(function() {return (selected == sF) ;})
                    .attr("display", display);

                console.log(selected);

            });
```

the whole code i worked on : [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/RI61bueRTwSWovqegNt7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite you `change` event handler this way:

```
dropDown.on("change", function () {
    var selected = this.value;

    hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
        .filter(function(d) {return (selected !== d[0]); })
        .attr("display", 'none');

    hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
        .filter(function(d) {return (selected === d[0]); })
        .attr("display", 'inline')
        .each(function(d) { helpers.mouseover(d) });
});
```

Where `helpers.mouseover` it is `mouseover` event handler for rectangles.

Check full code in [my fork of your plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZ9tUyJrQ0UgGf160jsJ?p=preview)

Comment: ok but can the pie chart data also get generated according to the visible location's data?? is it possible?

Comment: @Yogapriya Yes, it is possible. I updated my answer and plunker, check it.