# Create an "All" option in a dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have added a dropdown filter to the chart wherein the content gets loaded using the data:

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/VaRmWaI619T5cscBDbNh?p=preview)

Now am trying to add "All" as the default option tag which on select removes the filter and resets chart back to normal(just like a reset button).

```
//create dropdown filter options
                var defaultOption = dropDown.append("option")
                    .data(sF)
                    .text("All")
                    .attr("value", "select")
                    .enter();

                var options = dropDown.selectAll("option")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("option");

                options.text(function (d) { return d.State; })
                    .attr("value", function (d) { return d.State; });

            dropDown.on("", function () {
                var selected = this.value;

                hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
                    .filter(function (d) { return (selected !== d[0]); })
                    .attr("display", 'none');

                hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
                    .filter(function (d) { return (selected === d[0]); })
                    .attr("display", 'inline')
                    .each(function (d) { helpers.mouseover(d) });



              // Does something like this work?

                /* hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
                    .filter(function (d) { return (selected === d[0]); })
                    .attr("display", 'inline')
                    .each(function (d) {
                        if (selected === "select") { helpers.mouseout(d) } 
                        else { helpers.mouseover(d) }
                }); */
```

refer the [Previous version of the Chart](http://plnkr.co/edit/RI61bueRTwSWovqegNt7?p=preview). The first option doesn't work unless it is selected after another option.

[#47393325](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393325/d3-js-function-to-filter-the-interactive-chart/)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't need this:

```
hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
    .filter(function(d) {
        return (selected !== d[0]);
    })
    .attr("display", 'none');

hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
    .filter(function(d) {
        return (selected === d[0]);
    })
    .attr("display", 'inline')
```

All that code can be condensed in a single ternary:

```
hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
    .attr("display", function(d) {
        return selected === d[0] ? 'inline' : 'none'
    })
```

That being said, just add `"All"` in that ternary:

```
hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
    .attr("display", function(d) {
        return selected === 'All' ? 'inline' : selected === d[0] ? 'inline' : 'none';
    })
```

Or even shorter:

```
hGsvg.selectAll(".bar")
    .attr("display", function(d) {
        return selected === 'All' || selected === d[0] ? 'inline' : 'none';
    })
```

Here is the updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iV9r1JCuLQzqdiNcMfqc?p=preview

Comment: thanks!! but actual first location "TamilNadu" is been replaced by "All". What to do about that?

Comment: That has nothing to do with your question here. Please, don't ask additional questions in the comments. If you have further issues, post **another** question. Anyway, here is the solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/47lhnfbs2ddAeFHqtrDv?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a ton man!! am a new user, ill get used to the site and brief my questions properly from the next time..

Comment: Hey, the pie chart is not loading the data if i apply this code. (scroll vertically)

Comment: Use the original filter/each combination.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little issue when adding options to your dropdown. In your demo the first state option (TamilNadu) is missing from the dropdown.

To fix that I suggest to simply add a class to the options, like this. Updated your [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/InIKyc46UHMNerlUEPAF?p=preview)

```
//create dropdown filter options
var defaultOption = dropDown.append("option")
                    .data(sF)
                    .text("All")
                    .attr("value", "select")
                    .classed("default", true)
                    .enter();

var options = dropDown.selectAll("option.state")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter()
                    .append("option")
                    .classed("state", true);
```

You can discover more about the d3 update pattern reading [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).